# How to enable intellisense in VSCode for chaincode development (Hyperledger Fabric)

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

Facing issues with vscode intellisense not working while writing chaincode. This is Hyperledger Fabric chaincode development with vscode

'use strict';

const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class CertnetContract extends Contract {

```
constructor() {
    super("certnet"); 
}

async instantiate(ctx) {
    console.log("chaincode was successfully deployed");
}

//Create Student Asset
async createStudent(ctx, studentId, studentName, studentEmail) {

    //create compositeKey
    const studentKey = ctx. -----> here the intellisense not working
}
```

}